# Detect when Spark component is shown or hidden by state change

Tags: flex4, state, flex-spark

I have a Spark component that runs some animations when is visible (through a Timer).

The component is supposed to:

- suspend the timer when its is hidden and
- resume the timer when its shown again.

.

```
<!-- RandomButton.mxml-->
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Button xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
          xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
          creationComplete="start()">
    <fx:Script><![CDATA[
        public var ticker:Timer = new Timer(1000, 0)

        private function start():void {
            ticker.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, function(e:TimerEvent):void {
                label = '' + Math.random()
            })
        }
    ]]></fx:Script>
</s:Button>
```

Here is how the goal can be achieved with **enterState** + **exitState**:

```
<!-- Main.mxml -->
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<s:Application
        xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        xmlns="*">
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout/>
    </s:layout>

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="STATE_1"
                 enterState="b.ticker.start()"
                 exitState="b.ticker.stop()"/>
        <s:State name="STATE_2"/>
    </s:states>

    <s:Button label="STATE_1" click="currentState='STATE_1'"/>
    <s:Button label="STATE_2" click="currentState='STATE_2'"/>

    <RandomButton id="b" includeIn="STATE_1"/>
    <s:Label text="Debug: {b.label}"/>

</s:Application>
```

When STATE_2 button is clicked, the timer stops -- you can see that 'debug' label stops as well.

You can see that RandomButton needs some outside "assistance" to deal with its internal problems. This means copying enterState/exitState to any place where RandomButton is going to be used. Which is just sad.

**THE QUESTION**

I want RandomButton to maintain its state **by itself**. Like this:

```
<!-- Main.mxml -->
...
    <s:states>
        <s:State name="STATE_1"/><!-- no need to poke inside the RandomButton -->
        <s:State name="STATE_2"/>
    </s:states>
...

<!-- RandomButton.mxml -->
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Button xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
          xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
          creationComplete="start()"

          whenShown="ticker.start()"
          whenHidden="ticker.stop()" >
    ...
</s:Button>
```

Attributes **whenShown** and **whenHidden** dont exist. These are just a wish.

NOTE: there are **show** and **hide** attributes, but they deal with **visible** property (which remains set to **true** regardless of state changes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
<!-- RandomButton.mxml -->
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Button xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
          xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"

          addedToStage="ticker.start()"
          removedFromStage="ticker.stop()"
    ...
</s:Button>
```